# How do I sort my NSSArray that contains a nested JSON string?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

I am receiving JSON in the following format that I parse and store in a NSArray:

```
{"4eb57e72c7e24c014f000000":{"_id":{"$id":"4eb57e72c7e24c014f000000"},"author":"tim","comments":[],"created":{"sec":1320517234,"usec":856000},"picture":"http://someurl.com","text":"this is a test","title":"test","type":["test"]}
```

How do I get it to sort by "created"? "created" has the sec which appears to be the date and usec that appears to be the time.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you parsing the JSON?  What kind of objects does the parser return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:  You'll need a method that returns "Sec" from your JSON value.

Write A comparison function something like:

```
NSInteger intSort(id num1, id num2, void *context)
{
    int v1 = [num1 getSecFromJSONValue];
    int v2 = [num2 getSecFromJSONValue];
    if (v1 < v2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the `sortedArrayUsing...` methods.  Or (horror of horrors) write your own code to sort.